# Site not resolving on Att 3g network through Iphone

Tags: domain-name-system, iphone, 3g

I have a website www.example.com and it works fine everywhere except when using 3g on my iphone, even works on Edge network.  I have installed ping on my iphone and when on 3g it is says unable to DNS lookup host address.  I do not have an A record for www.example.com, instead have a cname to an ELB on Amazon.  I did try a test and added an A record for a subdomain test.example.com and that did work on 3g. So to me either Att has some DNS issues on 3g or it only works with an A record.  Any help would be great.  One other thing I can get to the site over 3g if I go directly to the ELB, which really makes me think its DNS,  I just dont know where to go from here as its been 3 days now. Thanks

Comment: I used the ip and it resolves so it's a dns issue with them. I am unable to change dns provider on my iPhone. It's been messed up for 3 days what can I do?

Comment: What is the TTL (time to live) setting on the DNS records?

Comment: 14400,  I have waited much more than that.  I also added a sub domain like i mentioned with an a record and that showed up within 4 hours

Comment: no its 14400 seconds

Answer (score 1):

That's a DNS issue at AT&T; they're probably using different resolvers for 3G vs. EDGE.

Try browsing to your site using just the IP first to make sure it's not a routing issue, of course, but if ping is reporting a failure on lookup then it's assuredly a DNS issue. Probably. (Unless it's having issues routing to the resolvers, in which case you'd notice a LOT more weirdness.)

If your phone supports it, you may want to change your resolvers. Google has a public resolver, 8.8.8.8

I prefer using Level3's public resolvers, because they report true NXDOMAIN instead of a redirect for nonexistent DNS records:

4.2.2.1
4.2.2.2
4.2.2.3

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue related to the dualstack implementation on AT&T's DNS servers. Try creating a CNAME record using the IPv4 (first entry in the list) domain listed in AWS ELB settings.

[image]